# Laravel Redirect::to() not working

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, laravel-4

I am creating a twitter log in feature for my project, the oauth step where the user has granted permission for my app to use their data returns the user to the /twitter-auth route, this route in turn initiates this method:

```
public function auth() {
    /* Oauth token */ 
    $token = Input::get('oauth_token');

    /* Verifier token */
    $verifier = Input::get('oauth_verifier');

    /* Request access token */
    $accessToken = Twitter::oAuthAccessToken($token, $verifier);


    /* Set the session variables from the acccess token above */
    Session::set('user_id', $accessToken['user_id']);
    Session::set('username', $accessToken['screen_name']);
    Session::set('oauth_token', $accessToken['oauth_token']);
    Session::set('oauth_token_secret', $accessToken['oauth_token_secret']);

    /* Determine if the user already exists in the database, if he/she does, then
    only update the user, otherwise, store a new user. Also pass an instance of the 
    accessToken as flash data in both instances. */
    if( User::where('twitter_id', $accessToken['user_id'])->first() == null )
    {

        $newUser = array(
            'username' => $accessToken['screen_name'],
            'oauth_token' => $accessToken['oauth_token'],
            'oauth_token_secret' => $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'],
            'twitter_id' => $accessToken['user_id']
        );

        User::create( $newUser );
        return Redirect::to('/');

    }

    else
    {
        $userToUpdate = User::where('twitter_id', Session::get('user_id'))->first();

        $userToUpdate->username = $accessToken['screen_name'];
        $userToUpdate->oauth_token = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $userToUpdate->oauth_token_secret = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $userToUpdate->twitter_id = $accessToken['user_id'];

        $userToUpdate->save();
        return Redirect::to('/');

    }


}
```

The user is saved/updated as necessary, but the user is not redirected to the home page. This happens with the redirect code both inside and outside of the IF statement. I was wondering if anyone could give me any clues as to why the redirect isn't working?

Comment: Try `if(User::create($newUser)) return Redirect::to('/')`, if it doesn't work, make sure you are entering in the `if` last statement.

Comment: Is this a controller action? If not, provide context of what is calling it.

Comment: Artsemis - It is a class that implements an OAuth interface. I have a controller and in the constructor I inject the Oauth interface as a  dependency, and then the class that holds this method is resolved via the IoC container. And I will try that now werewolf thank you.

Comment: I get the same result werewolf.

Comment: Some more context as to what is calling this: Twitter redirects the user back to appurl/twitter-auth, this triggers a route that invokes the controller method that leads to the method above being called via dependency injection like I said above, sorry if my first comment wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that in your controller, you return the Redirect class that is from auth() function.
Just tested your code and works :

let's say you have a UserController :

routes.php

```
Route::get('twitter-auth',array('as'=>'twitter-auth', 'uses'=>'UserController@twitterAuth'));
```

UserController 
   the user model class is just passed by dependency injection, to test this part also.

```
<?php

class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct(User $u){
        $this->user = $u;
    }


    public function twitterAuth(){

        return $this->user->auth();



    }

}
```

User model : 
I had to modify the code a little to fit my setup also

```
public function auth(){

    /* Oauth token */ 
    $token = Input::get('oauth_token');

    /* Verifier token */
    $verifier = Input::get('oauth_verifier');

    /* Request access token */
    //$accessToken = Twitter::oAuthAccessToken($token, $verifier);
    //emulate the request of access Token
    $accessToken = [
        'user_id'=>'11',
        'screen_name'=>'fewfewfew',
        'oauth_token'=>'12312321',
        'oauth_token_secret'=>'12312232323'
    ];

    /* Set the session variables from the acccess token above */
    Session::set('user_id', $accessToken['user_id']);
    Session::set('username', $accessToken['screen_name']);
    Session::set('oauth_token', $accessToken['oauth_token']);
    Session::set('oauth_token_secret', $accessToken['oauth_token_secret']);


    /* Determine if the user already exists in the database, if he/she does, then
    only update the user, otherwise, store a new user. Also pass an instance of the 
    accessToken as flash data in both instances. */
    if( User::where('twitter_id', $accessToken['user_id'])->first() == null )
    {

        $newUser = array(
            'username' => $accessToken['screen_name'],
            'oauth_token' => $accessToken['oauth_token'],
            'oauth_token_secret' => $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'],
            'twitter_id' => $accessToken['user_id']
        );

        User::create( $newUser );
        return Redirect::to('/');

    }

    else
    {
        $userToUpdate = User::where('twitter_id', Session::get('user_id'))->first();

        $userToUpdate->username = $accessToken['screen_name'];
        $userToUpdate->oauth_token = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $userToUpdate->oauth_token_secret = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $userToUpdate->twitter_id = $accessToken['user_id'];

        $userToUpdate->save();
        return Redirect::to('/');

    }


}
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'll try this out in the morning. Do you have any idea why moving the auth method to the user model would fix the redirect issue I am having?

Comment: it's not changing anything, i just tested it out having a delegate function, you can place that function anywhere , as long as you return what the functions returns ( what i did in controller )

Comment: Oh wow thank you thank you thank you, I had no idea that you added the return to the controller method. That makes perfect sense. This has been bugging me for days now :D

Answer (score 3):

**You are missing a `return`**

your function in this case `auth()` is returning the `Redirect` object but is the function calling your `auth()` function is returning the result back to the controller?

Comment: All you did was read the accepted answer, and *guess that it was right*. Without the accepted answer, you had literally *no way at all* to know this was the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately @AndrewBarber your analysis is incorrect. I was facing the same problem > looking for solution on stackoverflow > not finding the solution > debugging it until finding the solution > and sharing the solution with others :D

Answer (score 2):

Returning a Redirect to execute it is only possible from routes, controller actions and filters. Otherwise you have to call send()

Redirect::to('login')->send();